# Possible starvation in striped pool with deadlock true - Apache Ignite

Tags: java, c#, .net, ignite

I have an issue regarding Apache Ignite. My test is did with a Ignite server (written in java that use the continuous query to receive the notifications of the changed variables) and a Ignite client (written in .Net that use the putAll method to send the notifications of 1000 variables that vary every 50 milliseconds).
Each putAll sent around 350 variables simultaneously.
The error that i receive is:

> 2017-07-11 09:56:33,491 [WARN  ] [grid-timeout-worker-#19%null%] G -
>    Possible starvation in striped pool.
>       Thread name: sys-stripe-9-#10%null%
>       Queue: [Message closure [msg=GridIoMessage [plc=2, topic=TOPIC_CACHE, topicOrd=8, ordered=false, timeout=0,
>   skipOnTimeout=false, msg=GridNearAtomicFullUpdateRequest
>   [keys=[KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=117, val=null, hasValBytes=true],
>   KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=670, val=null, hasValBytes=true]],
>   conflictTtls=null, conflictExpireTimes=null, expiryPlc=null,
>   initSize=0, filter=null, parent=GridNearAtomicAbstractUpdateRequest
>   [res=null, flags=keepBinary]]]]]
>       Deadlock: true
>       Completed: 4941 Thread [name="sys-stripe-9-#10%null%", id=22, state=BLOCKED, blockCnt=6, waitCnt=4889]
>       Lock [object=o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCacheEntry@541d822b,
>   ownerName=sys-stripe-5-#6%null%, ownerId=18]
>           at sun.misc.Unsafe.monitorEnter(Native Method)
>           at o.a.i.i.util.GridUnsafe.monitorEnter(GridUnsafe.java:1193)
>           at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.lockEntries(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:2815)
>           at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateAllAsyncInternal0(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1741)
>           at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateAllAsyncInternal(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1630)
>           at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.processNearAtomicUpdateRequest(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:3016)
>           at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.access$400(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:127)
>           at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache$6.apply(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:282)
>           at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache$6.apply(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:277)
>           at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.processMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:863)
>           at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.onMessage0(GridCacheIoManager.java:386)
>           at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:308)
>           at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.access$000(GridCacheIoManager.java:100)
>           at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager$1.onMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:253)
>           at o.a.i.i.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1257)
>           at o.a.i.i.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:885)
>           at o.a.i.i.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$2100(GridIoManager.java:114)
>           at o.a.i.i.managers.communication.GridIoManager$7.run(GridIoManager.java:802)
>           at o.a.i.i.util.StripedExecutor$Stripe.run(StripedExecutor.java:483)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Are values from argument of putAll in sorted order?

Comment: No.. i don't implement any order for that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort Collection before applying it to the putAll, batch operations on the same entries in different order could lead to deadlocks.

Comment: Thank you for you response. So it means that i cannot use the putAll in a multi thread system?

Comment: You can use putAll in multi-threaded environment but you need to sort keys for it always at he same order

Comment: Hi @EvgeniiZhuravlev can you provide some explanation on why this happens? I think we are facing the same issue, but I've not found any entry about this in documentation. Seems like an important part of the batch operations API contract or?!

Comment: You can find it in JavaDoc: https://www.gridgain.com/sdk/ce/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteCache.html#putAll-java.util.Map-

Answer (score 0):

The same issue occurred when we try to put JsonObject in Cache. So instead of put operation, we have used putAsync and it works proper